# How can I pass data to a dynamically created page?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a web application for keeping up with basketball teams, games, schedules, etc. I have a page with a grid of team logos and when a team's logo is clicked I want it to pass the team name to a team details page that is populated using javascript based on the value passed from the team page. What's the best way to do this?

This is an example of the code for a team's logo

```html
<li>
  <figure>
    <a data-fancybox-group="group" href="img1.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="img.jpg" alt=""><i class="icon-signs23"></i></a>
    <figcaption>
      <h6><a href="teamDetails.html">Rockets</a></h6>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</li>
```

Comment: <a href="teamDetails.html?name=rockets">Rockets</a>

Comment: I'm afraid that this can only be achieved using witchcraft. and by witchcraft, i mean google.

Answer (score 0):

you can user **query string** in href, example code :

```
<a href="teamDetails.html?name=rockets">Rockets</a>
```

and in new page you can get value with :

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const name = urlParams.get('name');
```